# File not found in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, html

I'm using Javascript, where I need to read a file. I run it locally and it works perfectly, but when I try to do it running Django server, it fails because it doesn't find the file.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Here it is the error that Django gives

> [12/Jul/2018 12:37:36] "GET /ListadoCanciones/jugar/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7265
>   Not Found: /ListadoCanciones/jugar/DrumsInfo.csv
>   [12/Jul/2018 12:37:36] "GET /ListadoCanciones/jugar/DrumsInfo.csv TTP/1.1" 404 3842

Comment: Please post the actual code that tries to read the file. Perhaps it is cased wrong. `DrumsInfo.csv` will read `drumsinfo.csv` on a windows machine but not on a server

Comment: Do you have permission to read the file?

Comment: I assume he would have seeing the 200 OK on the index.html or whatever it is

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. I was not loading it statically. I added the following sentence where I wanted to read the file and the problem has been solved.

```
{% load static %}
leeArchivo("{% static 'MIDIPIRCUSSION_APP/DrumsInfo.csv' %}",song);
```